# Polygon Edge local node: cant ADD transaction to TX POOL

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, matic

I already have a local Polygon-Edge blockchain running on my system. It is working as expected with four nodes running (I can query address balances, for example, and it works just fine).

Now I'm following the Polygon Edge documentation to ADD a new transaction into the TX POOL, this is what the documentation:

https://edge-docs.polygon.technology/docs/working-with-node/query-json-rpc

> Step 4: Send a transfer transaction Now that we've confirmed the
> account we set up as premined has the correct balance, we can transfer
> some ether:
>
> polygon-edge txpool add --nonce 0 --from
> 0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010 --to
> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000010 --value 0x100 The txpool
> add command adds the transaction to the transaction pool.
>
> In this case, the transfer is from
> 0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010 to
> 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000010, with the value being 0x100
> wei.

When I run that command I get this output:

```
$ polygon-edge txpool add --nonce 0 --from 0x1010101010101010101010101010101010101010 --to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000010 --value 0x100 --grpc-address localhost:10000
Error: unknown flag: --nonce
Usage:
   txpool [command]

Available Commands:
  status      Returns the number of transactions in the transaction pool
  subscribe   Logs specific TxPool events

Flags:
      --grpc-address string   the GRPC interface (default "127.0.0.1:9632")
  -h, --help                  help for txpool

Global Flags:
      --json   get all outputs in json format (default false)

Use " txpool [command] --help" for more information about a command.

unknown flag: --nonce
```

As you can see in the output there is no "ADD" command. The documentation seems to be wrong...

**What is the correct way to generate a new transaction between addresses on my local instance?**